# How to make Sub Menu Always visible

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have menu navigation how to make sub menu always visible on the homepage only?

Thank You

[Here is my website](https://pc.haen.co.id)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see you have a homepage parent class (.home) with body tag, so its easy,

Try this,

```
.home .vertical-navigation .vertical-menu{
  opacity:1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```